# Jquery sortable and draggable helper function change element onclick for single element while having multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to make a looking like Wordpress cms (backend part) thing. It is possible to add multiple, exactly the same, header elements where a user can write inside and safe. Creating/adding all works. Dragging, dropping and sorting also works (jquery-ui). I already made all exactly the same heading elements have an diffrent ID using var "index"). The problem is that I cant get the id of the heading element I clicked. I need this so I ONLY change color, font-size and text-color to the one I clicked, and not to all of them... I think all my code is getting very messy and need to ask you guys because I am stuck :(

Like the code is right now, it works perfectly for just 1 of the draggable objects. I want it to work for mutliple.

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
var index = 0;
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: false,
        });

        $(".draggableElement").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            revert: "invalid",
            //helper: "clone"
            helper: function(){
                $("#removeDiv").remove();

                var element = '\
                <div id="containerHeader_'+index+'" class="bg-light w-100 mb-3 h-auto">\
                    <div class="border-bottom p-2 d-flex">\
                        <button id="firstHeader" onclick="headingOne()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H1</button>\
                        <button id="secondHeader" onclick="headingTwo()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H2</button>\
                        <button id="thirdHeader" onclick="headingThree()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H3</button>\
                        <button id="fourthHeader" onclick="headingFour()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H4</button>\
                        <button id="fifthHeader" onclick="headingFive()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H5</button>\
                        <button id="sixtHeader" onclick="headingSix()" class="mr-2 font-weight-500 cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-0 outline-none">H6</button>\
                    </div>\
                    <input id="headingInput" class="form-control border-0 shadow-none testen-class large-input" placeholder="Heading"></input>\
                </div>';
                index ++;
                return element;
            }
        });
    });

    {# $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstHeader").click(function() {
            alert("clik");
        });
    }); #}

    function headingOne() {
        $("#headingInput").css('font-size', '3rem');
        $(".font-weight-500").css('color', 'black');
        $("#firstHeader").css('color', '#0069d9');

        //console.log("containerHeader_"+index);
        //$("containerHeader_"+index).find("#firstHeader").css('color', '#0069d9');
    }

    //function headingTwo, three, four ... Exactly the same
</script>
```

The blue buttons in the left top are draggable, after the drag they transform into the "Heading" part with H1 H2 H3 etc. I dragged 2 Heading elements into the page. Only the first one is always working... Hope this edit helps to make it more clear.

Here is the image:
[image]

This is my HTML, of the draggable buttons.

```html
<div class="border-top d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap pt-3 px-3">
    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Header">
            <i class="fas fa-heading fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Text">
            <i class="fas fa-align-left fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Image">
            <i class="far fa-image fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Audio">
            <i class="fas fa-volume-up fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link">
            <i class="fas fa-link fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center pb-3 flex-30 draggableElement">
        <div class="btn btn-primary custom-padding-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Video">
            <i class="fas fa-video fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Sortable
<div class="container bg-secondary input-group p-3">
    <div class="container gray input-group w-100" id="testContainer">
        <div class="w-100">
            <input class="form-control shadow-none large-input remove-border mb-3" placeholder="Titel"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
            <input class="form-control shadow-none remove-border mb-3" placeholder="Subtitel"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
            <textarea class="form-control shadow-none remove-border mb-3" placeholder="Samenvatting"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="w-100">
            <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sortable" class="py-3 w-100">
        <div id="removeDiv" class="text-center text-white">Drag in here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle / HTML .

Comment: On its way... :) Never used it before so might take a while untill I get it finished...

Comment: I think jsfiddle is not going to happen. I will try adding a screenshot. I need to implement way to much to make the code work in jsfiddle...

Comment: I have it local, so html view source wont work :( I will add html

Comment: How about this :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/utnbv4aw/6/    try to make it workable with your code. it is not working as per given code.

Comment: Okey I think you have all you need, a jsfiddle is not going to work for me sinds i need to implement jquery-ui draggable/droppable/sortable, jquery itself, bootstrap and fontawesome.I think you need to only check the JS part. var element the first div has containerHeader_+index+. This index is important, its going +1 each time a new element will be dragged. So the new ID will be containerHeader_1 or 2 or 3 etc. I only want to now that, when I click on a button inside the container, wich one I clicked. Is it container_1 or 2? or maybe 52. Ty for ur help anyway @jit

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert button **id** to **class**.

```
 <button id="firstHeader"
```

to

```
 <button class="firstHeader"
```

and script becomes

```
$(".firstHeader").click(function() {
     alert($(this).parents(".bg-light").attr("id"));
});
```